# If I query a collection from firestore with 1 document with 10 text fields in it then will that count as 10 reads or 1 read?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I query a collection from firestore with 1 document with 10 text fields in it then will that count as 10 reads or 1 read? And how does the firestore count reads to a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll cost 1 read. You are charged for reads per document and not the amount of data in the document. Make sure you add a `limit` while fetching a collection:

```
citiesRef.orderBy("name").limit(3);
```

Since the limit here is 3, it'll charge you (at most) 3 reads. If there's no limit set then the query will fetch all documents costing you N reads where N is number of documents in that collection.

Read more at [Understanding Cloud Firestore Billing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing)

Comment: So, if i have link 10 fields in a single document then reading the document will only cost 1 read. Right?

Comment: @TomShaw yes only 1.

Comment: Thank You very much. I hope it is the same for array fields too with 10 elements.

Comment: I find it easiest to answer these questions by looking at the name of the charge: you are charged for **document** reads.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen. I'll keep that in mind :)